# How to pass Information in one page and Retrieve it in another?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

Hello I'm learning php but I'm hard stuck on what the next step should be.
I have a multidimensional array:

```
$fruits=array(
    array(
        "name"=>"The Banana", 
        "color"=> "Yellow", 
        "information"=>"bananas have lots of fiber."),
    array(
        "name"=>"The Strawberry", 
        "color"=> "Red", 
        "information"=>"strawberries have lots of vitamin."),
;
```

I'm able to show the array with my for each function

```
function show_fruits($fruits){    
    foreach($fruits as $fruit) 
        echo $fruit[name]."<br>".$fruit[color];
}
```

But now I want to pass the information into a new single page where it also shows the "information" key depending on the selection.

I was trying to use $_GET and embed the URL into my function but I was only getting "the" in the url result.

If anyone have better idea or how to proceed I would greatly appreciated!

Comment: For a complex data structure like this, I suggest using session.

Comment: You could use json_encode to create a json string and pass it. But best would probably be to use $_SESSION. Make sure you delete the $_SESSION after.

Answer (score 0):

You can store it in the $_SESSION global variable

Answer (score 0):

you can use $_SESSION if you want to pass the array from a page to an other, and include if you want to pass the function